# groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: in groovy on jenkins buildflow

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-build-flow

I am trying to run below code in jenkins build flow

```
def generator = { String alphabet, int n ->
new Random().with {
(1..n).collect { alphabet[ nextInt( alphabet.length() ) ] }.join() 
} 
}
pattern = '0x' + generator( (('A'..'F')+('0'..'9')).join(), 16 )
plintln "Random Pattern Created :" + pattern
```

output is below

> ERROR: Failed to run DSL Script groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No
>   signature of method: com.cloudbees.plugins.flow.FlowDelegate.plintln()
>   is applicable for argument types: (java.lang.String) values: [Random
>   Pattern Created :0xAC0E837A5284A407] Possible solutions:
>   println(java.lang.String), println(), println(java.io.PrintWriter),
>   println(java.lang.Object), print(java.lang.Object),
>   printf(java.lang.String, [Ljava.lang.Object;)     at
>   sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedConstructor.invoke(CachedConstructor.java:83)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.ConstructorSite$ConstructorSiteNoUnwrapNoCoerce.callConstructor(ConstructorSite.java:105)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCallConstructor(CallSiteArray.java:60)

Answer (score 1):

Please read the output (typo):

> Failed to run DSL Script groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No
>   signature of method:
>   com.cloudbees.plugins.flow.FlowDelegate.**plintln()** is applicable
>   for argument types: (java.lang.String) values: [Random Pattern Created
>   :0xAC0E837A5284A407] Possible solutions: **println**(java.lang.String)